# No values appearing in itertools groupby - python

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I am trying to group values in a string using python - `itertools.groupby`. I have tried using this code:

```
for key,values in itertools.groupby(s):
    print(key,list(values))
```

And I get this output:

```
a ['a']
b ['b']
a ['a', 'a']
b ['b', 'b', 'b']
c ['c']
```

which is fine. But when I add an `if` condition and change the code to in this way:

```
out = ''
for key,values in itertools.groupby(s):
    if len(list(values))==1:
        out+=key
    else:
        out += key
        out += str(len(list(values)))
    print(key,list(values))
```

I get this output:

```
a []
b []
a []
b []
c []
```

I don't know why the lists are being empty

Comment: because you use up the iterator here: `len(list(values))`

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get it. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values` is an iterator, you can only call `list()` on it once before it's used up. You should save that result in a variable & reuse it.

```
out = ''
for key,values in itertools.groupby(s):
    value_list = list(values)  # values iterator exhausted here, can't use it again
    if len(value_list)==1:
        out+=key
    else:
        out += key
        out += str(len(value_list))
    print(key,value_list)
```